# Combining text deletion & insertion in same code for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to insert text into text_box , delete text (only) leaving box on screen, sleep 1 second and put new text in same position in the text_box.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

from time import gmtime, strftime 
import datetime
global start_time, start
start_time = 0
start = 0
import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
print(start_time)

ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('400x300')
ws.config(bg='#84BF04')

def clear_text():
    text_box.delete(1.0, END)
    return

message ='''
Dear Reader,

    Thank you for giving your
    Love and Support to PythonGuides.
    PythonGuides is now available on 
    YouTube with the same name.

Thanks & Regards,
Team PythonGuides '''

frame = Frame(ws)

text_box = Text(
    frame,
    height=13,
    width=20,
    wrap='word'
)
text_box.insert('end', message)
text_box.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True)
text_box.config(state=NORMAL)  

sb = Scrollbar(frame)
sb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

text_box.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
sb.config(command=text_box.yview)

frame.pack(expand=True)

for count in range(1, 4):
    print(count)    
    clear_text()
    text_box.insert('end', count,"\r")
    text_box.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True)
    time.sleep(1)     
    
ws.mainloop()
```

I have tried to combine text widgit code with text_box code examples . The text_box will not appear until the count is over in my example code.

Comment: `time.sleep()` has no place in a Tkinter application - all it does is lock up the GUI for the specified duration.  Instead, you need to use the `.after()` widget method, to schedule a function call to be made after a specified delay.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this effect easily with the `after` method. This example uses `after` to repeat the function `update_text` until an iterable `messages` is exhausted

```
# here are some example 'messages' to iterate over
messages = ['Hello', 'there!', 'General', 'Kenobi...']


def update_text():
    try:
        text_box.delete('1.0', 'end')  # clear the current text
        message = messages.pop(0)  # get the next message from the list
        text_box.insert('end', message)  # update the text box
    except IndexError:  # no more messages!
        ws.after_cancel(text_loop)  # stop calling this function
        text_box.delete('1.0', 'end')  # clear the last of the text
    else:
        text_loop = ws.after(1000, update_text)  # call this function again after 1s


text_box.insert('end', message)  # insert welcome message
ws.after(1000, update_text)  # begin the update loop  after 1s
```

This might be overkill if all you want to do is update the text box periodically, but if you have a fixed number of predefined "messages" to loop over, it should do the trick!

NB: As written, this also assumes that the `messages` list *always starts with at least one string in it*. Otherwise you'll get an error when the first call to `update_text` fails on an `IndexError` and tries to call `after_cancel` on a non-existent `text_loop`. This is certainly avoidable, but I leave that to you to play around with! :)